# How to know when (Date and time) an index is dropped in sybase

Tags: sybase

On my clients machine we are using Sybase as a database, some one have dropped a clustered index on a table.

Now is there any way to find the date and time when the index on that table was dropped.

and please also let me know similarly to find the date time when a table was dropped as I suspect that dropping of the table will also drop the index on it ..

Thanks....

Comment: what version of sybase you are using? Do you have access to database backups?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have enabled auditing and audit the "drop event" or the specific user that run the command

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01672.1572/html/sec_admin/X23329.htm